# Reading in file from the internet in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libcurl

So I have done my research on how to do it and ended up with libcurl as the best option. However all the guides to implementing the library into visual studio are quite outdated and/or not specific on how to get it running.

I found [this one guide](http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/) and followed the instructions exactly as described but when running...

```
#include <ostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

...it says it cannot find curl/curl.h which puzzles me.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and/or other easier ways to go about this? In the end, all I need is to read something [like this xml file](http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30002659&typeid=17464) into the c++ program that I am making so that I can use this data for later use.

I also found [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf) but the date is from way back 2002 so I didn't even try it.

Should I perhaps use a different programming language? I was into using c++ since it's pretty fast for most things unlike python, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using visual studio IDE (inferred from stdafx.h inclusion) You have to add curl directory ( directory where curl is present e.g. if curl.h is at c:\sdk\curl\curl.h, add c:\sdk ) into Additional Include Directories ( right click project -> properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, it worked!
Was there any point to the other steps or should I just undo some of them for cleanliness purposes?
Also, I have no clue what stdafx.h does, but it was in some of the tutorials/guides I read.
Also, when i make an executable of the program, will the library work as if it were there too?

Comment: You have to add liker -> input -> Additional dependencies also put .dll files either in PATH or parallel to application executable.